# Can EE support authentication via a private oauth server?

Tags: authentication, oauth

I want to use EE to power the editorial portions of a larger commerce application, and I'd lover to offer a single sign-on experience.

There are add-ons allowing 3rd party sign on from Social networks, is there anything that allows support for a private oauth server?

Comment: Only thing I've found looks out of date an quite pricey: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/socialee. Depending on your developer skills and knowledge of oAuth, it sholdn't be too hard. I wrote an addon that allows single-sign on authentication from a LDAP.

Comment: I was looking at that — I have a question out to the devs to see if it can be repurposed to do what I need. ($130 is reasonable in the context of a large, multi-system project :D)